# Which Mandarin learning textbooks have the largest amount of practical exercises?

Tags: traditional-characters, resources, learning, books

I recently bought "Integrated Chinese Level 1 Part 1" (Traditional Characters version) after some recommendations on a few language blogs and have worked through a few chapters.

I feel that it's very slow-paced and lacking grammar exercises. After reading further online reviews (Amazon, Goodreads, etc.), others seem to share the sentiment that it's a good textbook for university/teacher-assisted learning but not so much for self-study, and that the rest of the series is indeed quite poor in exercises (and even lacks a proper Answer Key!).

Considering the textbook series is also quite expensive, what are the most comprehensive options for intensive practical exercises?

My only major requirement is that it's in Traditional Characters as I'm moving to Taiwan.

Answer (score 8):

You can find some bookstores near the Elementary Schools (小學).
If you see some signs like 國小參考書, go to find 參考書 (references) or 評量題 (examinations) for the first or second grade (一、二年級). 參考書 include the teachings in the textbooks and some Q&A. 評量題 have only Q&A.

You should know that all of them are totally in Chinese, no English.

(Ask your Taiwanese friends to go with you.)

You can find many Q&A on [全國中小學題庫網](http://exam.naer.edu.tw/).